# Do we know the Effects of "RELU Activation Functions" on the Convexity of the Loss Functions in Neural Networks?

Tags: r, neural-networks, optimization, loss-functions, gradient

**Do we know the Effect of "RELU Activation Functions" on the Convexity of the Loss Functions in Neural Networks?**

I have heard the following argument being made regarding Neural Networks:

- Sigmoid Activation Functions are Non-Convex Functions
- Loss Functions for Neural Networks that contain several Sigmoid Activation Functions are thus Non-Convex

Using the R programming language, I plotted the second derivative of the Sigmoid Function and we can see that it fails the Convexity Test (i.e. the second derivative can take both positive and negative values):

```
e = 2.718

eq = function(x){ (-e^-x)* (1+e^-x)^-2  + (e^-x)*(-2*(1+e^-x)^-3 *(-e^-x))}

plot(eq(-100:100), type='l', main = "Plot of Second Derivative of the Sigmoid Function")
```

[image]

**My Question:** (If the above argument is in fact true) Can the same argument be extended to lack of Convexity of Loss Functions of Neural Networks containing several "RELU Activation Functions" ?

"RELU Activation Functions" are said to solve certain problems that occur (e.g. vanishing gradient, exploding gradient) when training Neural Networks:

[image]

**However, the discontinuities and the differentiability of the "RELU Activation Function" make it unclear to me whether or not Loss Functions that contain "RELU Activation Functions" would automatically be Convex or Non-Convex.**

Can someone please comment on this? Due to the behavior of RELU Activation Functions-  do Neural Networks with RELU Activation Functions "automatically" become Non-Convex?

Thanks!

**References:**

- https://ml-cheatsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/activation_functions.html

**Note:** Using some informal logic, I do not think that the Loss Functions of Neural Networks containing RELU Activation Functions are generally Convex. This is because RELU (style) Activation Functions are generally some of the most common types of activation functions being used - yet the same difficulties concerning mon-convex optimization still remain. Thus, I *would like to think* that Neural Networks with RELU Activation Functions are still generally non-convex.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not convex. Note that $-ReLU(x)$ is the composition of a ReLU with a  ($1\times 1$) linear layer.

Comment: @ Mike Hawk: Thank you so much for your answer! What is your logic for figuring this out? How do you know that the Loss Functions of Neural Networks with RELU Activation Functions are Non-Convex? Thank you so much!

Comment: @stats555, the answer gives a specific example of a non-convex function computed by a specific ReLU nn. so it cannot be true in general that the output of a relu nn is convex

Comment: @ Mike Hawk: Thank you so much for your reply! Can you please help me understand this: "How does -ReLU(x) being the composition of a ReLU with (1x1) linear layer" demonstrate that the loss functions of neural networks with ReLU activations can not be convex? If you have time, can you please further explain this? I greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: @stats555, it is not that that they cannot be convex, it is that they are not always convex. and if the output of the network is not convex (as in the -ReLU case) then there is no reason to expect why the loss function should be

Comment: @ Mike Hawk: Thank you so much for your reply! That is a very interesting point - " it is not that that they cannot be convex, it is that they are not always convex".

Comment: I am sorry to ask so many questions - but I still don't quite understand :

Comment: 1) why the output of the network is not -ReLU case non-convex? I am having trouble bridging the gap as to why -ReLU (or + ReLU) has the ability to bring non-convexity.

Comment: 2) what exactly is meant by "the output of the network"? Do you mean if Loss = (Y - Y*)^2 ; Y is the true function, and Y* is the approximation of the true function estimated through the neural network? Here, is Y* the "output of the network"?

Comment: 3) this is probably a silly question - but is there any way of knowing that "a function (e.g. the Loss Function) that contains a non-convex part, also becomes non-convex"? I.e. why is there no reason to expect that the loss function might be non non-convex? Is this a trivial fact - a function that contains another non-convex function is automatically non-convex?

Comment: Again - thank you so much for your help! I really appreciate it!

Comment: The answer to the main question and most of the comments to this question can be determined by consulting the definition of *convex*.