# Why do we always illustrate and depict the Loss Functions of Neural Networks as Non-Convex?

Tags: neural-networks, data-visualization, optimization, loss-functions, gradient-descent

**Why do we always illustrate and depict the Loss Functions of Neural Networks as Non-Convex?**

By doing a quick Google Images Search of "Loss Functions for Neural Networks" - we are generally shown the same types of pictures. The Loss Function is generally illustrated as a colorful and wavy/bumpy surface :

[image]

**My Question:** Does anyone know why we often use these kinds of illustrations? My impression is that we want to point out that the Loss Functions for Neural Networks are typically Non-Convex and characterized by such features as "Saddle Points" and "(Several) Local Minimums" - reinforcing the idea that Loss Functions in Neural Networks generally have complicated structures and behaviors, making them difficult for optimization algorithms to minimize and ultimately difficult to train.

**Is this assertion correct - Are the Loss Functions of Neural Networks generally illustrated as "Non Convex Functions", because they actually tend to be "Non Convex" in real life?** Can we ever mathematically show that the Loss Functions of Neural Networks tend to be Non Convex in real life? (E.g. Sigmoidal Activation Functions can be shown to be Non-Convex, thus Loss Functions that are comprised of Sigmoidal Activation Functions are also Non-Convex?)

Can someone please comment on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Because [they aren’t convex](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/106334/35989). This is an example from actual empirical research I used in [my other answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/325007/35989) that tries to visualize loss landscape of an actual neural network:

[image: Example of real-life, non-convex loss landscape. It looks like a very irregular valley in the mountains, with a lot of ups and downs, many smaller valleys and peaks. Clearly non-convex.]

(source: [https://www.cs.umd.edu/~tomg/projects/landscapes/](https://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Etomg/projects/landscapes/) and      [arXiv:1712.09913](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.09913))

Comment: @ Tim: Thank you so much for your answer! Even though this is probably a pretty obvious , I am trying to understand the math behind this : why are we so quick to say that the loss functions of neural networks are usually non-convex? out of curiosity, could we take the formal mathematical definition of convexity (e.g. provided here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function) and use it to establish that the loss functions of neural networks are usually non-convex? E.g. if the functional form of the loss function for a nn does not obey the convex definition - it must be non convex? thanks!

Comment: @stats555 check the first link I mentioned.

Comment: A beautiful one!

Comment: thanks everyone for your comments and answers! i have a similar question over here - can you please take a look at it if you have time? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/561522/do-we-know-the-effects-of-relu-activation-functions-on-the-convexity-of-the-lo thank you so much!